# Name should have albhabet only

Tags: javascript

I have wrote some code for validate the name,Whether it has albhabet
    It will throw error if it does not have albhabet
    The below code should show the error,But it not show the error message

```
var nameExpression = '/^[a-zA-Z]/';
var name = 'hello123';
if ( !nameExpression.test(name) )
    alert('Error:Please enter the valid name');
```

Comment: Your regexp means "starts with a lower- or uppercase Latin letter", so `'hello123` will match.

Comment: `var str = "Hello World!";
 var res = str.toUpperCase();`  Why you try this one ...

Comment: You should say English alphabet, if that's what you mean. (And, if you are talking about restricting a person's name, you are going to alienate a lot of people—including English speakers.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var nameExpression = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
var name = 'hello123';
if ( !nameExpression.test(name) )
    alert('Error:Please enter the valid name');
```

Explanation:
        1.nameExpression should not be string
        2. You should use end delimeter such as '$'
        Eg
        var nameExpression = /^[a-zA-Z]$/;

Answer (score 2):

- Remove the quotes from around your regular expression litteral. Otherwise it's just a string, not a RegExp.
- Add `$` in the end (`/^[a-zA-Z]$/`), so that it only matches strings that are entirely made of ASCII letters, not just *starting* with them.
- oh and thanks Pavlo and James, missed that one. Add a Kleene plus (`+`) so that it matches more than just *one* letter: `/^[a-zA-Z]+$/`

Extra tip: if you're parsing real names, not code, then you *should* expect non-ASCII letters. You're a bit screwed because JavaScript regexes don't support Unicode yet, but this is a start:

```
/^[^\s\d]+$/i
```